# Preventing global variables in jsdoc output

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm currently documenting my JS files with jsdoc, but I'm running into some trouble. I have 2 files, `file1.js` and `file2.js` (not their real names obviously). Both these files contain a number of functions which I have documented in jsdoc style. When I run jsdoc on both files simultaneously, the output is a list of global functions with their descriptions. There is no distinction between where the functions are actually located (be it in `file1.js` or `file2.js`). Is there any way I can create this distinction in order to give my documentation a better structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `@module` tag in each file:

```
/**
 * @module file1
 */
```

You'd use `file2` for your other file. I've assumed your modules would have the same name as your files.

Then when you want to refer to things that are in a module, you use the `module:` notation. So if your `file1` module contains a class named `foo`. You'd refer to it to note the type of data a function in another module returns with `@returns {module:file1~foo}`. The tilde notation is explained [here](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html). It just indicates that `foo` is an "inner" member of the module `file1`. (Making it a "static" member would be better in my opinion but the current version of jsdoc does not handle it well for modules.)